# Animating a layout refresh crossfade

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

Android noob here, I have a function in my main activity that refreshes the weather data; it does this by calling the functions in two fragments that pull fresh data from a web API. I want the two fragment layouts to crossfade when you hit the refresh button/change the location and I can't seem to get animateLayoutChanges = "true" to do what I expect (crossfade when the views are set to View.GONE and back to View.VISIBLE). Am I doing things in the wrong order??

My Code:

```
 public void refreshCity(){

        //This block sets references to the fragment layouts and sets them to GONE

        RelativeLayout wfLayout =  (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_weather);
        LinearLayout ffLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_forecast);
        wfLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ffLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //This block gets references to the fragments themselves and calls the
        //changeCity function in each with the current city - this block definitely works

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        WeatherFragment wf = (WeatherFragment)fm
                .findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 0));
        ForecastFragment ff = (ForecastFragment)fm
                .findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 1));
        CityPreference cf = new CityPreference(this);
        wf.changeCity(cf.getCity());
        ff.changeCity(cf.getCity());

        //I then set the layouts back to visible

        wfLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ffLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The fragments refresh and display the data but there is no fade. animateLayoutChanges is set to true in both fragment layouts, is there some protection for referencing the layouts outside the fragments that they refer to? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with; I scrapped using the animateLayoutChanges in the xml files and added a ViewPropertyAnimator to each of the fragment's changeCity() functions (that are used to update the data displayed in the views).

```
public void changeCity(final String city){
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)getActivity()
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_forecast);
        layout.animate().setDuration(600);
        layout.animate().alpha(0);
        Runnable endAction = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateForecastData(city);
                layout.animate().alpha(1);
            }
        };
        layout.animate().withEndAction(endAction);
    }
```

The calls to update the data and fade the view back in I placed within a runnable that is called with the ViewPropertyAnimator function `withEndAction(Runnable runnable)` which only runs once the current animation has finished, so the views fade out -> the endAction runnable is run, the data is updated -> the views are faded back in.